# CDM display not working for users, but works as root

Tags: display, debian, xorg, display-manager

If I run CDM (Console Display Manager) as root, it works fine.
If I run it as any other user, CDM loads, requests a choice for WM, and then exits.
There is no readable output to stdout or stderr.

How can I debug this?

I turned on [logging of startx](https://github.com/12qu/cdm/commit/d897a5232311f06c9b2b373b8d4ba62ed26cf296) output. It says this:

```
X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

BTW, I am running Debian Jessie, if that helps.

Comment: I think this is intended behavior, because Xorg itself (still) isn't very good at starting as a regular user. Not with restricted graphics drivers anyway.

Comment: Scanning the source code, I found `setsid startx "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1 &`. Is it possible to add a sudo to the beginning of that line, so that I can run CDM as normal user and only elevate when starting X.

Comment: also you could just have run this ::> sudo -su root startx

Answer (score 1):

Got it!!!

Followed [this guide](http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2010/09/26/how-to-fix-x-user-not-authorized-to-run-the-x-server-aborting/) which allows ALL users to start the xserver. Previously I had it on console users only. Presumably, since CDM is launching xserver via a script, rather than an interactive console, it doesn't count as a console user.